# angular2 http.get() doesn't send request to the server

Tags: api, http, angular, get, angular2-services

I am trying to perform a get request to my api on localhost from my angular app. But for some reason the angular http client seems not to perform the get request.

I can see on my api server that no get request was made. And this is causing the error. The api is working fine I tried doing a curl and I get the expected results.

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

**api.service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response, URLSearchParams, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
    headers: Headers = new Headers({
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });

    api_url: string = 'http://localhost:5001';

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    private getJson(response: Response) {
        return response.json().results;
    }

    checkForError(response: Response): Response {
        if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
            return response;
        } else {
            var error = new Error(response.statusText);
            error['response'] = response;
            Observable.throw(error);
        }
    }

    get(path: string, params: URLSearchParams): Observable<any> {
        return this.http
            .get(`${this.api_url}${path}/`, { headers: this.headers })
            .map(this.checkForError)
            .catch(err => Observable.throw(err))
            .map(this.getJson);
    }
```

**api.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ApiService } from './api.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'item',
    templateUrl: './item.component.html'
})
export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {
    private itemData;
    private errorAlert;

    constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {}

      ngOnInit() {
          this.apiService.get('/items').subscribe(
              result => this.itemData = result,
              error => this.errorAlert = {msg: error, type: 'danger', closable: true},
          );
      }
}
```

Attached the console
[image]
[image]

Comment: In `checkForError` there should be a `return` before `Observable.throw(error)` but that seems unrelated to your error message. `map(getJson)` should be `map(this.getJson)`.

Comment: The observable doesn't do anything before `subscribe()` is called. Because `subscribe()` fails there can't be a request.

Comment: Provide some screenshot from network tab of dev tools

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer anyway the get request should start

Comment: What do you mean with "should start". If `subscribe()` fails, it won't do anything.

Comment: Can you please post the stack trace to the error message above?

Comment: Posted the console error trace to the question.

Comment: Can you please try with simplified `get()` method like `return this.http
            .get(``${this.api_url}${path}/``, { headers: this.headers }).map(res => res.json())` if you get the same error.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I tried that, I get the same error. It seems there is something with websocket form the network log. But any idea to solve the problem.

Comment: @SalmaHamed could you please copy compiled js

Comment: Sorry, no idea. So the error seems unrelated to the code you posted in your question.

Comment: @ValikhanAkhmedov which compiled js ?.

Comment: @SalmaHamed the compiled code of your apiservice

Comment: @ValikhanAkhmedov I am using webpack and the application is bundled into a huge js file. So if you can direct me how can I get what you are asking for.

Comment: @SalmaHamed just ctrl+f with "apiservice" find a chunk of js code and paste it here, if it's not minificated)

Comment: Have you tried this ,.  `import 'rxjs/Rx` in component???

Comment: @micronyks yes, noting change.

Comment: Does your request hit the server?

Comment: @micronyks no it doesn't.

Comment: Man, please show js code, I am very curious about it =)

Comment: @ValikhanAkhmedov well I have the typescript code already posted. If you can direct me of where to get the compiled js code, then am going to post it :)

Comment: @SalmaHamed maybe you can upload the bundle file?

Comment: try to change the name of `get` method. use something else like `getdata`. so it becomes `this.apiService.getdata('/items')...`

Comment: @ValikhanAkhmedov It's working now, thanks for trying to help. I don't know why it stopped working in the first place. but after restarting things seem to work.

Comment: Thanks guys it seems a sockets problem not relevant question, so I will just delete the question (A).

Comment: cheers then ! enjoy !

Comment: Don't delete the question. Make your own answer that might help others .

Comment: @SalmaHamed Man, I believe that your code wasn't compiled because you had an error with missing "this".

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should try to backtrack (or forward-track) the problem:

start with:

```
 this.http.get('/my/hardcoded/url').subscribe();
```

The problem might be in the headers or in the interpolated url or anywhere.